# Subscribe method is throwing error while trying to access kafka (0.90 version) from kafka (0.10 version)

Tags: apache-kafka, subscribe, consumer

This is our development environment

1)  kafka cluster  - version is 0.10 
2)  Spark cluster  - 1.6 which has 0.9 Kafka jars

We are trying to produce() and consume() in spark cluster mode. (via spark-submit)

While running spark-submit job, spark chooses 0.9 version of kafka. The following is our observation

1)  Producer – works fine ( 0.9 api and 0.10 api producer is compatible )
2)  Streaming Kafka Consumer using KafkaUtils – works fine ( seems here also 0.9 api and 0.10 api producer is compatible)
3)  Consumer using subscribe() API – Errors out with the following message. Can someone help us know why is it failing ?

> 16/10/24 02:31:08 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V
>           at com.common.kafka.init(Kafkafunction.java:150)
>           at com.client.Client.main(Client.java:100)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:542)
>   16/10/24 02:31:08 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating all the stuff up to `0.10` solves the problem. These versions are definitely not compatible in this line `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V`